# What are the minimal role attributes required for odoo day-to-day use?

Tags: database, postgresql, odoo, roles, access-rights

Most tutorials to setup [odoo](https://www.odoo.com) ERP create a superuser role for the web app user, which is odoo everywhere too, except [in the documentation where it is said](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/administration/install/deploy.html#configuration-sample):

> For the database management screen to be completely non-functional, the PostgreSQL
> user needs to be created with no-createdb and the database must be owned by a
> different PostgreSQL user.

> Warning: the PostgreSQL user must not be a superuser

But I don't manage to find what are the minimal roles required in order to fulfil the minimum rights principle for day-to-day role, so excluding administration (updating, adding modules).

Answer (score 1):

Any tutorial that recommends using a superuser is untrustworthy.

To create a role `odoo` that can create anything it wants in database `mydb`, you could connect to `mydb` and run:

```
/*
 * It would be better to create the role without password
 * and set it in a more secure fashion later.
 */
CREATE ROLE odoo LOGIN PASSWORD 'whatever';
GRANT CREATE ON DATABASE mydb TO odoo;
CREATE SCHEMA myapp AUTHORIZATION odoo;
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
ALTER DATABASE mydb SET search_path = myapp, public;
```

The creation of a separate schema for your application objects is not absolutely necessary, but a good idea in my opinion.

Comment: Are `schema` compatible with `odoo`?

Comment: I don't know. But if not, then Odoo is even worse than I heard it is.

Comment: Is it? I am interested if you have some links on the topic.

Comment: It is only hearsay. Anyway, you don't need t create a schema and set `search_path`. But why don't you try it out?